# How to do drag & drop with wxWidgets module of Python?

Tags: python, drag-and-drop, wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm using Python and I want to do a drag & drop interface.
For example, with a large picture whose size is bigger then the screen, I want to click on it and drag it to see other parts. Something like "google maps"!

In google maps if we click two times we do "zoom" but if we click one time and while pressed, we move the mouse, we move around the map. That's what I want to do!

Is it possible to do this using wxWidgets module of Python?
If so, how?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you mean "zoom"? Drag and drop would be dragging a file from your File Manager "into" your program, for example.

Comment: in google maps if we click two times it is "zoom" but if we click one time and then move the mouse we move around the map. That's what I want to do, do you understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution over here:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Python/Event/Mouseactiondrag.htm

With this code I can do what I want!

And the name was only Mouse Drag and not Mouse Drag and Drop (soz)